# Requisição POST com OkHttp em JAVA

Tags: java, okhttp

Minha pergunta é assim, eu to usando o postman pra simular essas requisições, aí quando eu escolho lá pra mostrar o código como seria em java mostra esse código abaixo, porém ta cheio de "caracteres estranhos" como esse `WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW`, e se eu retirá-los não funciona a requisição quando testo aqui. Alguém saberia dizer do que se trata esses códigos, e como seria a forma correta de eu enviar um post, com os dados que eu quero,um JSON por exemplo, sem ter que acrescentar esses códigos, ou pelo menos alguma classe ou método que gere automaticamente esses códigos ao enviar a requisição?

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW");
RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, "------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"grant_type\"\r\n\r\npassword\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"client_id\"\r\n\r\ntestclient\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"client_secret\"\r\n\r\ntestpass\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"username\"\r\n\r\nchaves\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"password\"\r\n\r\ndiscovoador\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--");
Request request = new Request.Builder()
  .url("http://api.sualoja.com.br/oauth")
  .post(body)
  .addHeader("content-type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW")
  .addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
  .addHeader("postman-token", "ae657120-da97-0123-ed66-bea56efdd3a8")
  .build();

Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

Comment: O que você está perguntando? Qual é a sua dúvida?

Comment: foi mal, dei enter sem querer aqui.Se não tiver mt bem explicado me avise pra eu editar. E obr por editar a minha pergunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sua requisição tem isso daqui:

```
multipart/form-data
```

Ou seja, é uma requisição multipart, uma requisição que como o nome diz é constituída de múltiplas partes. Essas partes são separadas uma das outras por um separador, que é o boundary. Esse boundary foi especificado pelo navegador de acordo com a [RFC 2046](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2046.txt) como sendo `----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW`. Essa string tem esse formato bizarro porque não pode ser nada que tenha qualquer chance de aparecer naturalmente nos dados a serem enviados.

Vamos ver o conteúdo da sua requisição:

```
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"grant_type\"

password
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"client_id\"

testclient
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"client_secret\"

testpass
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"username\"

chaves
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"password\"

discovoador
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--
```

Há 5 partes aqui. Cada parte contém um cabeçalho `Content-Disposition` e um corpo que é uma palavra. Os cabeçalhos e o corpo de cada parte são separados por uma linha em branco.

Acho que o que você queria é isso:

```
String json = ""
        + "{"
            + "\"grant_type\": \"password\","
            + "\"client_id\": \"testclient\","
            + "\"client_secret\": \"testpass\","
            + "\"username\": \"chaves\","
            + "\"password\": \"discovoador\""
        + "}";

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");
RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, json);
Request request = new Request.Builder()
  .url("http://api.sualoja.com.br/oauth")
  .post(body)
  .addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
  .addHeader("postman-token", "ae657120-da97-0123-ed66-bea56efdd3a8")
  .build();

Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

Comment: Então inevitavelmente, quando eu for fazer um POST, msm que seja um JSON por exemplo, eu preciso seguir exatamente essa lógica? E "adaptar" os dados contidos no meu json, para esse formato?

Comment: @TheJ Não. Apenas se você quiser fazer um post multipart. No entanto, acho que o multipart não é o que você quer.

Comment: O meu objetivo é por exemplo, pegar um login e uma senha, e mandar para esta API do postman,para que ele verifique no banco de dados se os dados existem e se estão corretos.Como se fosse um sistema de login mas feito em java SE

Comment: @TheJ Editei a resposta. Veja se o código no final funciona.

Comment: Não funcionou. Deu `Invalid request`.

Comment: @TheJ Tentei dar mais uma alterada com base [nesta resposta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34180100/540552). Tirei a definição explícita do header `Content-Type` porque o `MediaType` já implica nisso.

Comment: Deu certo, voce apenas mudou o campo `grant-type` para `grant-name`. Arrumei e funcionou.Obg.

Comment: Preciso abrir outra pergunta para saber como eu pego os dados que me são retornados?

Comment: @TheJ Ok, mesmo já tendo sido resolvido, arrumei a resposta para colocar `grant_type` para ficar registrado o correto, desculpe-me o errinho. Quanto aos dados retornados, sugiro abrir outra pergunta, até mesmo porque essa é uma outra dúvida e pode ser que uma outra pessoa saiba responder e também perguntas que ficam mudando muito o que está sendo perguntado não sem bem vistas por aqui, então é melhor não correr risco com isso.

Comment: Tranquilo, e eu descobri aqui ja como pegar kk É bem simples na vdd  utilizei `response.body().string()`. No mais obrigado pela ajuda.